# iTunes media collection on the network

Tags: macos, itunes, media-server

So, my movies and music collection keeps expanding, and it seems to make more sense to move all media from my Macbook to a separate media server (especially if I am to get an SSD).

But it seems that I'm making iPhone syncing incredibly tedious if not outright impossible. `mt-daapd` (on Debian) works fine if I just want to stream music to iTunes, but there is no way to sync it to the iPhone, not to mention managing the collection (tagging, renaming, adding).

Anyone has a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

if you have a fast LAN - ethernet gigabit i think you can setup a samba share and point your itunes library at it.  My understanding is that as long as itunes can resolve the share then it should work.  Your itunes library file would still be on your machine i think.  I am also curious in this solution and interested in hearing others responses.

Comment: Wireless, actually. So reliability may not be too good.